# How to open field explorer in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am working on `Crystal Reports` in `VS 2010`. I unexpectedly closed `Field Explorer` from left side of `Visual Studio` and now I don't know how to open it again. I searched it in `Edit` and `View` menu but didn't find it.

Can you please guide me how to open field explorer in `Visual studio`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`View > Other Windows > Document Online`

Yet, you should ask google first.

Comment: That's how we come here ;)

Answer (score 0):

**View > Other Windows > Document outline not online**